# Calling methods in a Java Fx ActionEvent

Tags: java, javafx, actionevent

I'm new to JavaFX and I want to create a view class that will call methods in a Controller when an event is triggered by a button push. My code is below:

```
package spacetrader.menu;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import spacetrader.Window;

public class MenuView implements Initializable {
    public Window window;
    public MenuCtrl menuCtrl;

    @FXML
    Button start;
    @FXML
    Pane background;
    @FXML
    Button exit;

    public MenuView() {};

    public MenuView(Window aWindow, MenuCtrl aMenuCtrl) {
        window = aWindow;
        menuCtrl = aMenuCtrl;
    }

    void renderMainMenu() {
        try {
            window.loadFXML(new FXMLLoader((getClass().getResource("MainMenu.fxml"))));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MenuView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        start.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> menuCtrl.newGame());
        exit.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> menuCtrl.closeApplication());
    }
}
```

This compiles, but when I run it and press the button I get a null pointer exception on the lambda expressions. The exception refers to "menuCtrl." How should I be setting up my program to make the button call menuCtrl.newGame()?

Here's what I've tried already:

- I've moved the setOnAction commands to between the various methods.
- Replaced the calls to menuCtrl methods with System.out.prinln statements to confirm that this works. It does.
- I've replaced menuCtrl methods with System.out.println(this) to ensure there isn't a scoping problem. It prints "spacetrader.menu.MenuView@74f51979" as expected.
- Converted the Lambda expressions to anonymous inner classes
- Used a block as the lambda's body

Comment: Is this class the controller class for the same FXML it loads?  (i.e. does MainMenu.fxml have `fx:controller="MenuView"` as an attribute in the root element?) That would be an unusual setup, at least the way you have it here.

Comment: Yes the fx:controller in MainMenu.fxml is MenuView. Why is that strange?

Comment: Because you have to create one instance of the controller in order to load the FXML, which then creates another instance of the controller. Typically you would load the FXML from a different class (the exception perhaps being if you are using a [dynamic root](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#custom_components) (which looks very different).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setup is unusual, in that your controller class (which you've called `MenuView`) is the class that calls (indirectly, via your `Window` class) the FXMLLoader's load method. The `FXMLLoader` parses the FXML, sees the `fx:controller` attribute, and consequently instantiates it using the default (no-argument) constructor. (I am making an assumption here that you don't call `setController` or `setControllerFactory` on the `FXMLLoader` in `Window.loadFXML`.) Thus you have two controller instances: the one which created the loader (for whom the initialize() method is never called and the `@FXML`-annotated fields are never injected), and one which was created by the `FXMLLoader` (which called the no-argument constructor, so the `window` and `menuCtrl` fields are not initialized for that instance).

You should either refactor this, so that the FXMLLoader is created and passed to the Window class for loading elsewhere (i.e. without instantiating the controller), or you should explicitly set the controller on the FXMLLoader. You can achieve the latter in two steps:

1. Remove the `fx:controller` attribute from MainMenu.fxml
2. Set the controller explicitly to the instance already created in your `renderMainMenu` method:

--

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader((getClass().getResource("MainMenu.fxml"))) ;
loader.setController(this);
window.loadFXML(loader);
```

Comment: You, sir, are amazing. I had a completely wrong idea of how the architecture for FX worked, and this cleared it all up.

Answer (score 0):

You may try using `Scene Builder` where drag and drop feature is available and you can design a screen in seconds. In code section you just have to declare method name and implement that method in code handler class.

You can get it from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/javafxscenebuilder-info-2157684.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have two constructors. My guess is that you're loading an FXML somewhere which will instantiate your controller using the no-args constructor. In this case menuCtrl is not initialized.

If you're instantiating menuCtrl in the FXML, then add a @FXML annotation to the field.